# Custom Post for Locating by Google Maps API

Tags: api, google, location-search

How do I set up a custom post so that it can be proximity geolocated with Google Maps API?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Unfortunately your question is likely to be voted closed as "off-topic" for this site.   It is open-ended and could receive numerous answers that might all be considered correct.  Very specific questions attempting to solve a very specific issue (geocoding locations with Google Maps, for example) usually generate good, useful answers.

Comment: ok, understood. Can I edit this question or shall I post a new one?

Comment: It's fine to edit the current question. :)